# object reference is required for the non-static field with constructor

Tags: .net, class, static, repository

```
 public class Auth
{

    private IBaseRepository<User> users;

    public Auth(IBaseRepository<User> users)
    {
        this.users = users;
    }

    private const string UserKey = "simpleBlog.Atuh.UserKey";

    public static User User
    {
        get
        {
            if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                return null;

            var user = HttpContext.Current.Items[UserKey] as User;

            if(user == null)
            {

                 user = users.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);

                if (user == null)
                    return null;

                HttpContext.Current.Items[UserKey] = user;

            }

            return user;
        }
    }

}
```

I Got an error in this part, but i dont know how to solve it.

```
user = users.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make this non-static:

```
public static User User
```

to

```
public User User
```

The class is written so that it would perfectly accept constructor injection. I'd instantiate it either once as needed (transient) or once per web request.

If you've never used dependency injection then this is the perfect scenario for trying it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is an instance field

```
private IBaseRepository<User> users;
```

but this is a static getter

```
public static User User
```

You cannot access the instance field `users` from a static getter.

One solution is to make `users` static, though I don't know whether or not that makes sense in the larger context of your code.